# Advanced Search of Messages for Multiple Words in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I would like to do an Advanced Search of messages for multiple words without having to do each one manually/separately.

If I could record a macro in Outlook 2016, which as I understand it I cannot do, these are the commands I would do:

- Record Macro
- Click on Search Current Mailbox.
- Click on Search Tools.
- Click Advanced Search.
- For the drop-down after “In:” choose “frequently-used text fields”.
- Type into “Search for the word(s):” the text to find.
  (Entering multiple words there means to find one string of all the words, not to find each word individually.)
- Click Find Now.
- Stop recording macro.
- Edit the VBA code produced to:

  - Specify the rest of the words to find
  - Specify case-insensitive
  - Then do the Find Now.

Then I would like to display them all.
Preferably sorted, but not necessary if will make it more complicated code.

From piecing together code found online, I have the code below.

- Subject is the only value I can use debug.print on.  The others give errors:

> "Run-time error '5':  Invalid procedure call or argument".

- I only know how to search on Subject.
- I do not know how to display the list of what I have found (not in Immediate window).

```vb
' Test VBA for Multiple-Word Search in Outlook - 3

Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()
 Dim Scope As String
 Dim Filter As String
 Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search
 Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table
 Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row
 m_SearchComplete = False

 'Establish scope folder
 Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath & "'"
Debug.Print Scope

 'Establish filter
 If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then
    Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"
Debug.Print Filter
    Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'rent'" _
             & " OR ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'breaking'"

'(subject:invoice OR body:invoice) AND hasattachments:yes NOT from:Amazon


 Else
    Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"
 End If
Debug.Print Filter

 Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")
 'While m_SearchComplete <> True
 '   DoEvents
 'Wend

 Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable
  Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable
    Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()
'Debug.Print nextRow("SentOnBehalfOf")
'    Debug.Print nextRow("From")
'    Debug.Print nextRow("ReceivedTime")
    Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")
 Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't provide a macro recorder like Word or Excel. You need to create a VBA macro manually in Outlook.

The [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article explains how to use the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook.

> The Outlook Object Model also provides the `AdvancedSearchStopped` event. The signatures of the `AdvancedSearchStopped` and `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event handlers are the same. The `AdvancedSearchStopped` event is triggered when the `Stop` method is called on the Search object to cancel searching. However, the `AdvancedSearchComplete` is called afterwards anyway.

> Admittedly, the `Search` class allows you to save the results of searching in a search folder (actually, it doesn’t contain any items, only references to items from the scope folders). You just need to call the `Save` method on the Search object in the `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event handler.

For example, in VBA you can define the `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event handler in the following way:

```
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
  If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then
    m_SearchComplete = True
  End If
End Sub
```